# Customizar o "Generate toString()..." do eclipse para imprimir o path de uma classe

Tags: java, eclipse

Como faço para customizar a função `Generate toString()` do eclipse  (source > Generate toString()) para imprimir o path de uma classe?

Por exemplo tenho a seguinte entidade que imprime:

```
package com.etc.model;

@Entity
@Table(name="CLIENTE")
public class Cliente implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;

@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cliente [id=" + id + "]";
    }
```

Como faço para configurar o generate toString() para sair com o path completo? No caso:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.etc.model.Cliente [id=" + id + "]";
    }
```

Uso a versão Neon.3

---

Obrigado pessoal pelo retorno, mas vou me expressar melhor. Preciso configurar o Generate ToString para **gerar o código com o path completo** (o que é visualizado em package) na classe java.

No exemplo mostrado acima ele gera mostrando o nome da classe Cliente:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cliente [id=" + id + "]";
    }
```

Como customizar ele para gerar o código com o path completo (o path é mostrado na linha do package):

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.etc.model.Cliente [id=" + id + "]";
    }
```

Veja que o path completo com o nome fica: **com.etc.model.Cliente** 
Parece que tenho que criar um novo format template, dei uma analisada nele através da [documentação](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-tostring-styles.htm) mas não consegui chegar ao que preciso.

Comment: Nenhuma das respostas lhe serviram?A minha eu testei e funcionou normalmente.

Comment: Obrigado @Articuno . Elas me auxiliaram.

Answer (score 2):

O jeito mais simples de fazer algo próximo a isso é alterar o template padrão nas configurações da IDE, indo em *`Source-> Generate toString()...`*

Em `String.format`, clique no botão <kbd>Edit...</kbd> e altere o template padrão que deve estar assim:

```
${object.className} [${member.name()}=${member.value}, ${otherMembers}]
```

para:

```
${object.getClassName} [${member.name()}=${member.value}, ${otherMembers}]
```

Esse `${object.getClassName}` será substituído no código por `getClass().getName()`, que retornará o nome completo da classe([leitura recomendada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242057/28595)), incluindo a hierarquia de pacotes. Demais argumentos irão exibir membros e métodos que a classe possuir.

Veja um exemplo abaixo com o método toString() gerado dessa forma sendo executada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se quiser mais customização que isso, recomendo que dê uma lida em [Generate toString() dialog(documentação Eclipse)](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-dialog-tostring.htm), pois parece ser algo mais profundo nas configurações da IDE.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, observei que no template default  do GeneratetoString() a variável ${object.className} resulta na geração do código mostrando somente do nome da classe, como se fosse um getSimpleName(). Preciso que ele gere com o nome completo (com a hierarquia da classe, no caso do seu exemplo o GeneratetoString deveria gerar:`@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "br.com.exemplo.TestClass [id=" + id + "]";
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Simples, basta usar o método [`getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()). Veja:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getName()+" [id=" + id + "]";
}
```