# Qual diferença entre os métodos getCanonicalName() e getName()?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem

Para retornar o nome do pacote com o nome da classe eu sempre usei o método `getName()`. No entanto [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242051/35406) do [@Articuno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/28595/articuno) da pergunta: [Customizar o Generate toString() do eclipse para imprimir o path de uma classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242048/customizar-o-generate-tostring-do-eclipse-para-imprimir-o-path-de-uma-classe), ele mostrou uma maneira diferente de fazer isso, porém usando o método `getCanonicalName()`, que no final retorna o mesmo resultado.

Veja só um exemplo customizando o método `toString()`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getName();
}
```

Que aparentemente seria equivalente a:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getCanonicalName();
}
```

Qual real diferença entre os métodos `getCanonicalName()` e `getName()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## TL;DR

A diferença entre o `getName()` e o `getCanonicalName()` são essas:

- Em classes arrays, o `getName()` vai retornar `[` seguido do `getName()` do componente-base. Já o `getCanonicalName()` vai retornar o `getCanonicalName()` do componente-base seguido de `[]`.
- Em classes aninhadas e classes internas, o `getName()` vai trazer o nome com algum `$` introduzido pelo compilador no meio. O `getCanonicalName()` vai trazer esse nome com o `$` substituído por um `.`.
- Em classes locais e classes anônimas (e em arrays dessas), o `getCanonicalName()` retorna `null`, enquanto que o `getName()` não.

## Resposta detalhada

Baseando-se na [minha resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29527145/540552):

Esse código abaixo mostra as diferenças entre `getName()`, `getCanonicalName()`, `getSimpleName()` e `toString()` para classes, interfaces, tipos primitivos, classes de arrays, classes aninhadas, classes internas, classes anônimas, classes locais e classes lambdas.

Além disso, também adiciono classes que são arrays de classes anônimas e arrays de lambdas (que no entanto não fazem nenhum sentido na prática):

```java
package com.example;

public final class TestClassNames {
    private static void showClass(Class<?> c) {
        System.out.println("getName(): " + c.getName());
        System.out.println("getCanonicalName(): " + c.getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println("getSimpleName(): " + c.getSimpleName());
        System.out.println("toString(): " + c.toString());
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void x(Runnable r) {
        showClass(r.getClass());
        showClass(java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(r.getClass(), 1).getClass()); // Obtém uma classe array cujo componente-base seja um lambda.
    }

    public static class NestedClass {}

    public class InnerClass {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class LocalClass {}
        showClass(void.class);
        showClass(int.class);
        showClass(String.class);
        showClass(Runnable.class);
        showClass(SomeEnum.class);
        showClass(SomeAnnotation.class);
        showClass(int[].class);
        showClass(String[].class);
        showClass(NestedClass.class);
        showClass(InnerClass.class);
        showClass(LocalClass.class);
        showClass(LocalClass[].class);
        Object anonymous = new java.io.Serializable() {};
        showClass(anonymous.getClass());
        showClass(java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(anonymous.getClass(), 1).getClass()); // Obtém uma classe array cujo componente-base seja uma classe anônima.
        x(() -> {});
    }
}

enum SomeEnum {
   BLUE, YELLOW, RED;
}

@interface SomeAnnotation {}
```

Eis a saída completa:

```
getName(): void
getCanonicalName(): void
getSimpleName(): void
toString(): void

getName(): int
getCanonicalName(): int
getSimpleName(): int
toString(): int

getName(): java.lang.String
getCanonicalName(): java.lang.String
getSimpleName(): String
toString(): class java.lang.String

getName(): java.lang.Runnable
getCanonicalName(): java.lang.Runnable
getSimpleName(): Runnable
toString(): interface java.lang.Runnable

getName(): com.example.SomeEnum
getCanonicalName(): com.example.SomeEnum
getSimpleName(): SomeEnum
toString(): class com.example.SomeEnum

getName(): com.example.SomeAnnotation
getCanonicalName(): com.example.SomeAnnotation
getSimpleName(): SomeAnnotation
toString(): interface com.example.SomeAnnotation

getName(): [I
getCanonicalName(): int[]
getSimpleName(): int[]
toString(): class [I

getName(): [Ljava.lang.String;
getCanonicalName(): java.lang.String[]
getSimpleName(): String[]
toString(): class [Ljava.lang.String;

getName(): com.example.TestClassNames$NestedClass
getCanonicalName(): com.example.TestClassNames.NestedClass
getSimpleName(): NestedClass
toString(): class com.example.TestClassNames$NestedClass

getName(): com.example.TestClassNames$InnerClass
getCanonicalName(): com.example.TestClassNames.InnerClass
getSimpleName(): InnerClass
toString(): class com.example.TestClassNames$InnerClass

getName(): com.example.TestClassNames$1LocalClass
getCanonicalName(): null
getSimpleName(): LocalClass
toString(): class com.example.TestClassNames$1LocalClass

getName(): [Lcom.example.TestClassNames$1LocalClass;
getCanonicalName(): null
getSimpleName(): LocalClass[]
toString(): class [Lcom.example.TestClassNames$1LocalClass;

getName(): com.example.TestClassNames$1
getCanonicalName(): null
getSimpleName(): 
toString(): class com.example.TestClassNames$1

getName(): [Lcom.example.TestClassNames$1;
getCanonicalName(): null
getSimpleName(): []
toString(): class [Lcom.example.TestClassNames$1;

getName(): com.example.TestClassNames$$Lambda$1/1175962212
getCanonicalName(): com.example.TestClassNames$$Lambda$1/1175962212
getSimpleName(): TestClassNames$$Lambda$1/1175962212
toString(): class com.example.TestClassNames$$Lambda$1/1175962212

getName(): [Lcom.example.TestClassNames$$Lambda$1;
getCanonicalName(): com.example.TestClassNames$$Lambda$1/1175962212[]
getSimpleName(): TestClassNames$$Lambda$1/1175962212[]
toString(): class [Lcom.example.TestClassNames$$Lambda$1;
```

Assim sendo, essas são as regras. Primeiro, vamos começar com os tipos primitivos e com o `void`:

1. Se o objeto da classe representa um tipo primitivo ou `void`, todos os quatro métodos devolverão o seu nome.

Agora, as regras para o método `getName()`:

2. Cada classe ou interface não-lambda e não-array (ou seja, de nível superior, aninhada, interna, local ou anônima) tem um nome (retornado pelo `getName()`) que consiste no nome do pacote seguido de um ponto (se houver um pacote), seguido do nome do arquivo de classe tal como gerado pelo compilador (sem o sufixo `.class`). Se não houver pacote, isso será simplesmente o nome do arquivo da classe. Se for uma classe interna, aninhada, local ou anônima, o compilador deverá gerar pelo menos um `$` em seu nome. Perceba que para classes anônimas, o nome da classe será terminado com um cifrão seguido de um número.
3. Nomes de classes lambda são em geral imprevisíveis, e você nem deveria se importar com eles. Precisamente, o nome delas é o nome da classe que os contém, seguido de `$$Lambda$`, seguido de um número, seguido de uma barra e seguido de mais um número.
4. O descritor da  classe para tipos primitivos é `Z` para `boolean`, `B` para `byte`, `S` para `short`, `C` para `char`, `I` para `int`, `J` para `long`, `F` para `float` e `D` para `double`. Para classes e interfaces não-arrays, o descritor da classe é composto de um `L` seguido pelo que é retornado por `getName()` e seguido de um `;`. Para classes array, o descritor é um `[` seguido do descritor da classe que é o componente-base do array (que por sua vez, pode ser uma outra classe array).
5. Para classes array, o método `getName()` retorna o descritor da classe. Essa regra parece falhar apenas para classes array cujo componente-base seja um lambda (o que possivelmente é um bug), mas isso provavelmente não importa porque não faz sentido sequer a existência de classes array cujo componente-base seja um lambda.

Agora, o método `toString()`:

6. Se a instância da classe representar uma interface (ou uma anotação, que é um tipo especial de interface), o `toString()` retorna `"interface " + getName()`. Se for um tipo primitivo, ele retorna simplesmente `getName()`. Se for qualquer outra coisa (um tipo classe, mesmo que seja um bem estranho), ele retorna `"class " + getName()`.

O método `getCanonicalName()`:

7. Para classes e interfaces de nível superior, o método `getCanonicalName()` retorna simplesmente o que o `getName()` retorna.
8. O método `getCanonicalName()` retorna `null` para classes anônimas e classes locais e para arrays dessas classes.
9. Para classes e interfaces internas e aninhadas, o método `getCanonicalName()` retorna o que o `getName()` iria retornar substituindo os cifrões introduzidos pelo compilador por pontos.
10. Para classes arrays, o método `getCanonicalName()` retorna `null` se o nome canônico da classe componente for `null`. Em caso contrário, ele retorna o nome canônico da classe componente seguido de `[]`.

O método `getSimpleName()`:

11. Para classes e interfaces de nível superior, aninhadas, internas ou locais, o `getSimpleName()` retorna o nome da classe ou interface tal como escrito no código-fonte.
12. Para classes anônimas, o `getSimpleName()` retorna uma `String` vazia.
13. Para classes lambda, o `getSimpleName()` retorna apenas o que o `getName()` retornaria sem o nome do pacote. Isso não tem sentido e acredito que seja um bug. Entretanto, nem mesmo faz sentido você chamar `getSimpleName()` em uma classe lambda para começo de conversa.
14. Para classes array, o método `getSimpleName()` retorna o nome simples da classe componente-base seguido de `[]`. Isto tem o curioso/estranho efeito colateral de que classes array cujo componente-base seja uma classe anônima terão apenas `[]` como seus nomes simples.